# find the order of unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have an array `long[100] arr;` and I want to "rank" the elements in the array. Meaning I want to know which one is the smallest, which one is the second smallest and so on.

I'm aware that I can make a copy, sort it, and then find each element from the sorted array in the unsorted one, but it seems a very cumbersome way to do this simple task.

Is there a function in Java that gives you the order of an unsorted array?
I know that in R there are 2 different function, `sort()` and `order()`, one for each task.

```
//example
long[] arr = {1983, 321, 63, 832, 455, 1466, 788, 25425, 1839}
Arrays.sort(arr); // arr = {63, 321, 455, 788, 832, 1466, 1839, 1983, 25425}
// I'm looking for a function that will give me this-
int[] order = foo(arr); // order = {7, 0, 8, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2}
```

Comment: "it seems a very cumbersome way to do this simple task"  Almost any solution I can think of is going to boil down to that anyway.

Comment: Note that your simple procedure (sort then look up) will produce inconsistent results if there are any duplicates, because the index of the second item will never be among the results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *could* create an array of the indexes, then sort it based on the values in the `long` array:

```
import java.util.*;

class Example {
    static Integer[] getSortedIndexes(final long[] arr) {
        Integer[] indexes = new Integer[arr.length];
        for (int n = 0; n < indexes.length; ++n) {
            indexes[n] = n;
        }
        Arrays.sort(indexes, (left, right) -> Long.compare(arr[right], arr[left]));
        return indexes;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] arr = {1983, 321, 63, 832, 455, 1466, 788, 25425, 1839};
        Integer[] indexes = getSortedIndexes(arr);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(indexes));
    }
}
```

With your sample input, that produces:

```
[7, 0, 8, 5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 2]
```

[Live on IDEone](http://ideone.com/YO3q9c)

I can't say it's pretty :-), but:

- You don't have to look up the indexes of the sorted result.
- It handles having two equivalent values in the original array correctly.
- It doesn't create a bunch of intermediate objects (though sadly it does involve `Integer` instances instead of just `int`s).
- It's simple.

If you want an `int[]` result, you'll have to add a pass at the end, either a simple `for` loop, or [`Stream#mapToInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) (fancier but heavier).

Or if you want to go whole-hog on streams, as [SkinnyJ points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43853903/find-the-order-of-unsorted-array#comment74746855_43854206):

```
static int[] getSortedIndexes(final long[] arr) {
    return IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed().sorted((right, left) -> Long.compare(arr[left], arr[right])).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

Comment: Don't compare `int` values by subtraction, since that may lead to overflow. Use [`Integer.compare(int x, int y)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead. --- Also, using Java 8 lambda, this code can be simplified, by removing the anonymous class boiler-plate code: `Arrays.sort(indexes, (i, j) -> Integer.compare(arr[i], arr[j]));`

Comment: @Andreas: Thanks! Even better, in this case, [`Long.compare(long, long)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#compare-long-long-) (as I need to compare longs). Updated!

Comment: @Andreas: Re lambda: Even better. I haven't done Java coding "in anger" since before lambdas came in, clearly if I'm going to pitch in here, I need to buck up my ideas! Updated again.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you can totally streamify this algorithm as `IntStream.range(0, arr.length).boxed().sorted((right, left) -> Long.compare(arr[left], arr[right])).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();`

Comment: @SkinnyJ if you don't bother using `Integer[]`, you can replace that `mapToInt(i->i).toArray()` to just `toArray(Integer[]::new)`

Comment: @JohnnyWiller do you mean "if you don't bother using `int[]`"? In that case, definitely, but it's not what the OP asked.

Comment: @SkinnyJ: Yeah, I was thinking it could be `stream`-ified but being new to streams I still hadn't worked it out when I had to take off. I'd gotten as far as `range`, `boxed`, and `sorted`, but...

Answer (score 4):

I'd use a [TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), reversing the keys and indexes. TreeMap orders iterations by the provided [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), so use [Comparator.reverseOrder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) to get the largest-to-smallest ordering:

```
int[] order(long[] arr) {
    Map<Long, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>(Comparator.reverseOrder());
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        map.put(arr[i], i);
    }
    return map.values().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

Here is a one-liner using streams:

```
int[] order(long[] arr) {
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
      .collect(() -> new TreeMap<Long, Integer>(Comparator.reverseOrder()),
               (map, i) -> map.put(arr[i], i), 
               Map::putAll)
      .values().stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```

Comment: This becomes a lot trickier if there are any duplicates in the source array, because the index that you are going to get is that of the last item among the duplicates.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight good point. You could make it fancier with TreeMap<Long, Collection<Integer>>

Comment: Of course you can, but the pure beauty of a five-line solution will be gone forever. When the numbers are unique, though, this is hard to beat.

Comment: OP said *"Meaning I want to know which one is the smallest, which one is the second smallest and so on."*, but this does the opposite -- gives the index of the largest first, then the next largest, etc. Easily fixed, of course.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added the `Comparator.reverseOrder()` and the `i+1` to match the OP's example, but obviously those could both be removed.

Comment: Thanks! that looks like what I'm looking for, I have no idea how to deal with this TreeMap, but I'll read about it.
I'm not sure if my data will have any duplicates or not, I'll check it.
Thank you both of you!

Comment: @SkinnyJ: Ah, with you now on the output.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this in a single `Stream` pipeline.

```
public static int[] order(long... ls) {
  //If ls == null then throw a NullPointerException
  Objects.requireNonNull(ls);
  //Generate a IntStream in range [0, ls.length[
  return IntStream.range(0, ls.length)
      //convert int to Integer
      .boxed()
      //Sort the numbers according to the value in the array
      .sorted(
         //Convenient function to create a Comparator.
         //Same as: (left, right) -> Long.compare(ls[right], ls[left])
         Comparator.comparingLong((Integer i) -> ls[i]).reversed()
      //Since values are boxed (i.e. Integer) convert back to int
      ).mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
      //Create the int array (i.e. int[])
      .toArray();
}
```

Comment: I got to say, I read your code 3 times, and still don't have a clue what's happening here.. :( a lot to learn I guess.

Comment: Thank you Flown, looks great! Learned a lot!